# "Message component not found!" When using Button Interactions in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

In discord.js when trying to use a button interaction, an error occurs saying "Message component not found!" The component it is trying to find is the "create_ticket" component which has been defined before the code where it tries to use it.

I was expecting for it to create a channel in the guild that the command was originally run in, this does not happen, instead this appears.

[image: Bot Response]

Here is the full code:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, EmbedBuilder, ButtonStyle } = require("discord.js"); // Include EmbedBuilder
const EmbedMaker = require('../modules/embed.js');
module.exports = {
    category: 'General',
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('modmail')
        .setDescription('Initiates the modmail process'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });

        try {
            const user = interaction.user;
            const initialEmbed = new EmbedBuilder() // Use EmbedBuilder
                .setTitle('Modmail')
                .setDescription('Hello, you have run the modmail command. Would you like to create a ticket?');

            const createButton = new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('create_ticket')
                .setLabel('Create Ticket')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success);

            const cancelButton = new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('cancel_ticket')
                .setLabel('Cancel')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger);

            const buttonRow = new ActionRowBuilder()
                .addComponents([createButton, cancelButton]);

            await user.send({ embeds: [initialEmbed], components: [buttonRow] });

            if (interaction.customId === 'create_ticket') {
                try {
                    // Create a ticket channel
                    const guild = interaction.guild; // Get the guild where the interaction occurred
                    const ticketCategoryID = '1139591568538476676'; // Replace with your category ID
        
                    const sanitizedUsername = user.username.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '').slice(0, 32);
                    const channel = await guild.channels.create(sanitizedUsername, {
                        type: 'text',
                        parent: ticketCategoryID,
                        permissionOverwrites: [
                            {
                                id: guild.id,
                                deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                            },
                            {
                                id: user.id,
                                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                            },
                        ],
                    });
        
                    const embed = new EmbedMaker(client) // Use the client instance
                        .setTitle('Modmail Ticket')
                        .setDescription('This is a modmail ticket. Messages sent here will be forwarded to the moderation team.');
        
                    await channel.send({ content: `<@${user.id}>`, embeds: [embed] });
        
                    const buttons = [
                        {
                            type: 1,
                            components: [
                                {
                                    type: 2,
                                    custom_id: 'close_ticket',
                                    label: 'Close Ticket',
                                    style: 4,
                                },
                            ],
                        },
                    ];
        
                    await channel.send({ content: 'Ticket created!', components: buttons });
        
                      // Handle user messages and send them to the ticket channel
            const dmChannel = await user.createDM();
            const collector = dmChannel.createMessageCollector({ filter: (msg) => !msg.author.bot });

            collector.on('collect', async (message) => {
                const userEmbed = new EmbedMaker(interaction.client)
                    .setDescription(message.content)
                    .setAuthor(user.username, user.displayAvatarURL());

                await channel.send({ embeds: [userEmbed] });
            });

            // Handle closing the ticket
            const closeCollector = channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ time: 60000 }); // Change the time as needed

            closeCollector.on('collect', async (interaction) => {
                if (interaction.customId === 'close_ticket') {
                    await interaction.update({ content: 'Ticket closed.', components: [] });

                    try {
                        await channel.send('Ticket has been closed.');
                        await channel.delete(); // Optionally delete the channel
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error('Error while deleting channel:', error);
                    }
                }
            });

            collector.on('end', collected => {
                if (collected.size === 0) {
                    dmChannel.send('Ticket creation process timed out.');
                }
            });
        
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error while creating ticket:', error);
                    await interaction.reply('An error occurred while creating the ticket. Please try again later.');
                }
            }
          

            // Send a follow-up message to the user
            await interaction.editReply('Check your DMs for the modmail command and further instructions.');

        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error while executing modmail command:', error);
            await interaction.editReply('An error occurred while executing the modmail command. Please try again later.');
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: can you provide the error stack, if possible?